# Linear models with multiple samples

Tags: regression

I have a data set describing seed moisture content of 26 different species as a product of relative humidity (rh).

```
species     |15% rh  |20% rh  |40% rh
--------------------------------------
species 1   |6.0     |8.4     |10.0
species 2   |5.8     |7.6     |9.4
species 3...
```

I would like to be able to say something like "With every 5% increase in relative humidity, there is--on average--an X percent increase in seed moisture content."

I first tried creating a multiple linear regression but that tells me about the relationship of each species to another. Instead, I would like a generalization of all the species together.

Should I instead find the mean (median?) value at each relative humidity measured and create a linear model of the mean?

Should I ignore the fact that they are repeated measures on the same species and simply make a linear model of all of the combined data?

suggestions welcome!

edited:
here's what I have so far. Each species is a separate color and the linear regression is in blue. This linear regression is simply using the entire data set. Does it take into account the fact that the measurements on the same species are related to each other, or does that not matter?

[image]

And, looking at my output for that linear model:

```
> Call: lm(formula = seedmoisture ~ rh, data = seeds)
> 
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -3.9229 -1.7258  0.1771  1.6742  5.5278 
> 
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     (Intercept) 2.176459   0.498542   4.366 2.66e-05 *** rh          0.143286   0.008771  16.337  < 2e-16 ***
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> Residual standard error: 2.151 on 123 degrees of freedom   (31
> observations deleted due to missingness) Multiple R-squared: 
> 0.6845,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.682  F-statistic: 266.9 on 1 and 123 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I see that for every 1% increase in relative humidity, I expect a 0.14% in seed moisture content.

sound right?

Comment: One method for repeated measurements would be to average the values for the same species (as you note) so that each species has a single value for the regression. Another would be to use weighted regression, where the weights are related to the number of measurements. As a first pass at the problem, I would use the "averages" method as it should give a good understanding without a more complex weighted regression. If you ignore the fact of repeated measurements, you would be in effect weighting the regression towards species with more measurements which is the opposite of what you want to do.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply!  I may have misused the term 'repeated measures.' I have only one measurement for each species at each relative humidity (15%, 20%, etc.). But I have 26 species that I want to be able to make a generalization for. For example "For any given species, if you increase the relative humidity by 5%, you are likely to see approximately "X" percent increase in seed moisture content."

Comment: Do you want to generalize to other than the 26 species in the sample? To see a difference between within-species and between-species variation, we would need multiple samples per species ...